# Reflection in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reflection, discord

anyone know how to use Reflection in Node.js/Discord I want to replace

my direct map property call:
Userlist.get(uid).Strength

with a more programic one like
var DamangeStateName = "Strength"
Userlist.get(uid).DamangeStateName

which would get the Strength property like the direct one.
The main reason I need reflection is because sometimes the Key attribute is "Agilty" not "Strength"
And while my code everwhere else works with the string variable my Map of the player data can't use those same tricks and i need to be able to use reflection os it synergies with the rest of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript, being a prototype-based language where everything is basically just a hashtable of strings to values, neither has nor needs reflection machinery in the sense that Java or C# have.

I think you want something like this:

```
Userlist.get(uid)[DamangeStateName]
```

Comment: you mean `Userlist.get(uid).[DamangeStateName]` or do i not need the dot notation

Comment: No, it doesn't work with the dot. It's just object indexing. `myObject.foo` is equivalent to `myObject['foo']`.

Comment: that worked but I'm experiencing a related problem

i have a secondary map which i initialize for every player with still like this (there are a lot more entries)
`
UserList.set(rows_db[i].id, {
FortuneFinder: {
Rank: 0,
LEVEL_OR_BONUS: 0
}
});
`
but when i try to update it later i get a "undefined error" when i try to look up
`UserSkillList.get(PlayerID).FortuneFinder.Rank`

but it should have at the very least due to initialization a 0
 so 1) why cant i access Rank and two when i need to eventually do reflection is it just
`UserSkillList.get(PlayerID)[DamageStateName]Rank`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need reflection for your stated problem. You want to be able to handle two keys that mean the same thing.

Extend the target item (object/class) with a method to wrap the logic.

`Userlist.get(uid).DamangeStateName`

`User.prototype.NormalizedDamangeStateName = function() { /* ... */ }`

My `User` is an assumption. You'll need to identify the correct object by determining what `Userlist.get(...)` returns...  Regardless, the concept should be sound.

Comment: What i need to do is be able to change the key as i change the string the default for "DamangeStateName" is strength but that could be overridden if the Primary attribute used for that skill the player is trying to use is say "perception"

which is why I kind of need reflection so I can just change "DamangestateName" and the Map of Userlist with fetch the data in 

`Userlist.get(uid).Perception`

instead of it always hard coding to `Userlist.get(uid).strength`